# Can't import twisted.internet.protocol module on mountain lion

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to implement a TCP server and using python script. So I created a `server.py` on my desktop and imported the following modules:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory,Protocol
```

It's already failing at that point, because if I run: `python server.py`, I got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory,Protocol
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol
```

I also use `sys.path` to print my Python directories and I got these outputs:

```
['/Users/Alfred/Desktop',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

What could have gone wrong with my python setup?

Is it because of the privilege of my account? I logged in as the admin on this machine.

Comment: How did you install twisted?

Comment: Did you manage to run this ray wenderlich tutorial? I still cannot find why it doesn't find twisted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your `sys.path`, you've installed Python from python.org, or compiled your own, rather than using the built-in Python that has Twisted pre-installed.  If you install your own Python, you have to install your own version of Twisted into that version of Python.  You can use `pip` or `easy_install` or download directly from [the Twisted site](http://twistedmatrix.com) and run `setup.py`.

`type -p python` in a shell will tell you which version you're using; I suspect it will be in `/usr/local/bin/`.

`/usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory,Protocol'` ought to succeed.  If not, then I don't know what you've done to your sytem Python installation :).

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I need to do, though I am getting "twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:80: [Errno 13] Permission denied." error after sucessfully installed my twisted and zope.interface. I am working solving this issue right now.

Comment: @Alfred - only root can listed on port numbers that are lower than 1024. If you are running it as a normal user, make sure you use a port number above 1024 that is not being used.  Also, if you have enabled "web sharing" in System Preferences, this starts up the bundled Apache server that listens on port 80.

Answer (score 3):

The output of `python -v -c 'import twisted.internet.protocol'` might reveal the problem.  As a first check, though, make sure you don't have a file named "twisted.py" sitting around.

Comment: Using the above command, it prints lots of comments, the few lines that are related to twisted looks like this:

Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol

Comment: Some of those things it prints are intended to tell you more about why the import fails.  Either read and interpret them, or add them to your question for someone else to read and interpret. :)  You can focus your attention on the ones that talk about twisted and mostly ignore all the rest about standard library modules and such.

Comment: You Sir are awesome! I've been trying to run twisted for two hours while having a twisted.py file in my folder:)